# how to copy data from one database to another database in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to copy tables from one postgresql8.4 to another postgresql8.4 and I am not sure how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just take `pg_dump` from one and import in another? Seems quite trivial. 
 Take a look at this:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to so it using a database link:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/contrib-dblink.html

Comment: Could you add a bit to that answer? I get "function dblink... does not exist".. Any idea's how to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

if you have postgres contrib installed you need to type this once is psql:

CREATE EXTENSION dblink;