# how to transfer rows from one postgreSQL 9.1.5 database on Heroku to another (also on Heroku)

Tags: heroku, postgresql-9.1

I have two Rails apps running on Heroku, each has its own PostgreSQL 9.1.5 database (with Amazon endpoints accessible by me)

Both apps are running the same codebase, so they initialise the two database using the same set of schema.  But App 1 only uses say Table A,B and C while App 2 only uses Table D and E.
(e.g. App 1's database's table D and E are empty)
Now, I need to move/copy all the data (table D and E ) from App 2's database to App 1's database (and then reconfig App 2 to use App 1's database from now on).

If I just take a pg_dump on App 2's database and restore it on App 1's database, it will erase the existing Table A,B and C rows, I believe.  Or is there any flag/option that I can set so that it will preserve the existing data?   Or what other methods I should look into?

Thanks!

P.S.
This post suggested pg_dump or database link, but after reading the pages, I am still not confident that I know how to use them so that my existing data won't be erased/overwritten

[how to copy data from one database to another database in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016065/how-to-copy-data-from-one-database-to-another-database-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

I would fork your database.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork

1. Create a backup of your db
2. Fork the db
3. Hook up App2 to your 2nd databse
4. Verify app1 and app2 are working find (and not writing to each others tables)
5. delete columns ABC from the new (app2) db
6. delete columns DE from the original (app1) db